How do I set up Nginx reverse proxy and nftables to encrypt HTTP through CGNAT? (Read description)
(repost off Network engineering stack exchange as that was not the right place.
My home network is behind CG-NAT and am not able to port forward. So, I have a Linode server configured to forward all traffic through WireGuard.
Local device ----{WireGuard}---> Linode server -----> Internet

However, I am now trying to set up an Immich server on the local device (old MacBook), and need to set up and Nginx reverse proxy on the Linode server, however it's just giving connection refused, even just trying to set up the proxy without HTTPS.
The WireGuard Router IP is 192.168.69.1 and the client is 192.168.69.2.
I'm trying to just forward all traffic from 192.168.69.2:2283 to <linode public ip>:2284 (where I will eventually set up HTTPS).
My nftables.conf is
table ip my_nat {
  chain my_prerouting {
    type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat;

    ip daddr <linode public ip> tcp dport { 80, 443, 53, 32400, 8181 } dnat to 192.168.69.2;
  }
  chain my_postrouting {
    type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat;

    ip saddr 192.168.69.2 masquerade
  }
  chain forwarder {
    type nat hook prerouting priority -100;
    tcp dport { 2284 } accept;
  }
}

table ip6 my_nat {
  chain my_prerouting {
    type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat;

    ip6 daddr <linode public ipv6> tcp dport { 80, 443, 53, 32400, 8181 } dnat to fd69::2;
  }
  chain my_postrouting {
    type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat;

    ip6 saddr fd69::2 masquerade
  }
}

My nginx config is
server {
    listen 2284;

    server_name <my domain name>;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.69.2:2283;
        include proxy_params;
    }
}


On your local MacBook, have you used netstat to confirm that your Immich setup is listening on 192.168.69.2:2283?

Also, when you said "I'm trying to just forward all traffic from 192.168.69.2:2283 to :2284", did you say that backwards?
